# Как вывести из бд данные на все страницы проекта python django

Tags: python, django, классы

По сути мне нужно метод shop встроить в класс ProductListView
Потому что вывод из метода shop выводит только на странице cart

```
class ProductsListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'shop/shop.html'


def shop(request):
    cart = Order.get_cart(request.user)
    items = cart.orderitem_set.all()
    context = {
        'cart': cart,
        'items': items,
        }
    return render(request, 'shop/shop.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
path('', views.ProductsListView.as_view(), name='shop'),
path('cart_view/', views.cart_view, name='cart_view'),
path('detail/<int:pk>/', views.ProductsDetailView.as_view(), name='shop_detail'),
path('delete_item/<int:pk>', views.CartDeleteItem.as_view(), name='cart_delete_item'),
path('add-item-to-cart/<int:pk>', views.add_item_to_cart, name='add_item_to_cart'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview), вы можете переопределить метод `get_context_data()`:

Пример из документации:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

from articles.models import Article

class ArticleListView(ListView):

    model = Article
    paginate_by = 100  # if pagination is desired

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context
```

В вашем случае это может быть так:

```
class ProductsListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'shop/shop.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        cart = Order.get_cart(self.request.user)
        items = cart.orderitem_set.all()
        context.update({
            'cart': cart,
            'items': items,
        })
        return context
```

Comment: Еще один вопрос, теперь это работает только для зарегистрированных пользователей, а как сделать что бы было доступно для незарегистрированных?

Comment: @Evgeniy, а почему в данный момент это доступно только для зарегистрированных пользователей? я не вижу у вас ни декоратора `login_required`, ни наследования от `LoginRequiredMixin`

Comment: Field 'id' expected a number but got <SimpleLazyObject: <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x10c16d3a0>>. 
Вот что выдает при переходе на страницу /shop/

Comment: ну а что вы ожидали, если в cart = Order.get_cart(self.request.user) вы пытаетесь взять юзера, которого нет. в данном случае вам тогда нужно сделать [проверку](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#attributes) на авторизованного или анонимного юзера, и только потом уже выполнять или нет код с корзиной.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое.